# Question when saving data through local storage

Tags: javascript

In the process of saving data to local storage.
I want to store objects in a key called 'DB'.
But I get an error saying "list.push is not a function." What's the problem?

```js
let list = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('DB'));

const index = number++;

if (!list) {
  const arr = [];
  arr.push({
    todo: text,
    index: index
  });
  localStorage.setItem("DB", JSON.stringify(arr));
} else {
  list.push({
    todo: text,
    index: index
  });
  console.log(list);
  localStorage.setItem("DB", JSON.stringify(list));
}
```

Comment: Is `list` an array?

Comment: On which line is this snippet throwing the error in question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you already have something stored in the storage item DB that does not parse to an array, the code will fail. If I run it twice it does what I assume you want it to do, and I get a stringified array with two objects in my localStorage.
I suggest you try again, and if you have problems check what's in your localStorage.

As an aside, your code could be streamlined a little. For example:

```
let list = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('DB'));

// Maybe print out list here, to see what it is immediately after parsing 
console.log('list:', list);

const index = number++;

if (!list) {
    list = [];
});

list.push({
    todo: text,
    index: index
});

localStorage.setItem("DB", JSON.stringify(list));
```